# Keeping Socket Alive with Vapor 3

Tags: swift, heroku, websocket, vapor

I have a web socket in an app built using Vapor 3 that I have deployed to Heroku. The socket keeps closing. How do I keep the socket alive in Vapor 3? In Vapor 2, I used these lines of code. How would I do the same thing in Vapor 3?

```
background {
    while ws.state == .open {
        try? ws.ping()
        self.console.wait(seconds: 10) // every 10 seconds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I used and it seems to be working well for my use case. If there is a better solution, let me know.

```
func runRepeatedTask() {
    _ = req.eventLoop.scheduleTask(in: .seconds(1)) { () -> Void in
        ws.send(Data())
        if socketOpen {
            runRepeatedTask()
        }
    }
}
runRepeatedTask()
```

I included this in my web socket function right above/below to `ws.onText({ ws, string in`. I hope this helps!